# Flushing Azure blob writes

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Let's say I have an Azure IaaS virtual machine with a mounted data disk (e.g. E: drive).  Then I copy 1000 files of varying sizes onto it.  As soon as Windows says the copy is complete I take a snapshot of the mounted data disk.

Here's the problem: if I mount that snapshot, some files are missing and others are corrupt.

However, if I wait a while after the copy is complete and then take a snapshot, all of the data is there.

This tells me there is some behind the scenes caching that's done, which is expected.  Is there any documentation available that discusses how Azure caches data before it's actually flushed to blobs?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the cache settings of your disks when you created it.
If you mounted the drive in azure with cache setting to "Write", then writes are cached and you should wait or turn off VMs to be safe.

You can play with [IaaS Management Studio](http://iaas.ao-is.com/) -evaluation for 30 days-, this tool, among other things, prevents you to take snapshot when it detects that your blob is a disk with cache settings to write. (I'm the dev behind this tool :))

Comment: Hi Nicolas.  Thanks for your information and link.  My data disk has its host cache setting to "None".  During development did you experience anything like I describe?  Basically on the VM, copy a bunch of files to the mounted blob drive, and the instant Windows says the copy is done take a snapshot of that blob drive.

Comment: Hi, I just tested and is seems to work fine for me. However, I've not looked in details if the files were correct. But nothing seems missing.